# For a positive definite matrix $Q$ and any square matrices $A_i$, if $\sum_{i=1}^pA_i^TQA<Q$, can we get $\rho(\sum_{i=1}^pA_i^TA)<1$?

Tags: positive-definite

I found that for a positive definite matrix $Q$ and a square matrix $A$, if $A^TQA<Q$, then $\rho(A)<1$.  But what if $\sum_{i=1}^pA_i^TQA<Q$? can we get $\rho(\sum_{i=1}^pA_i^TA)<1$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\rho(A)$?

Comment: $\rho(A)$ means the spectral radius of matrix A

Comment: And what do you mean by $A < B$ for matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: It means that $B-A$ is positive definite.